# Flutter Streambuilder + Firestore returning null snapshot after using background location plugin

Tags: flutter, background-process, stream-builder

After the addition of this plugin (https://pub.dev/packages/carp_background_location), all my Streambuilders with Firestore stopped working. It returns null for all snapshot.data of my app.

Situation:

1. StreamBuilder works for all collections from Firestore on the app
2. Use `carp_background_location` like on the `example/lib/main.dart` on a specific screen
3. All streams return null on snapshot.data on the app

Normal behaviour just comes back when I close the app and run main.dart again (and don't run background location).

This was the only plugin that worked for the case I needed with location (background), so changing the plugin would not be ideal. Actually I suspect that forcing the background work is causing this (maybe other plugins inside this plugin), but I am not able to find the answer. No error or warn is shown, what is making it more difficult.

Could someone help me on this please? Is there any function to get the "normal" behaviour after using the background plugin?

On this screen I am listening to Firestore with Streambuilder:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'begin_activity.dart';


class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainAppState createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void moveToPage() async {
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocationStreamWidget()),
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        mini: true,
        onPressed: () {
          moveToPage();
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 30,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,

      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: _firestore
                  .collection('users')
                  .doc('user_id')
                  .collection('corridas')
                  .orderBy('date', descending: true)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Center(
                      child: SpinKitCubeGrid(
                          size: 51.0, color: Colors.blue,));
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                } else if (snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty) {
                  return Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.55,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 50.0, 8.0, 0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.directions_run,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              Strings.noTracks,
                              style: TextParameters.noActivities,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ));
                } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final docAux = snapshot.data.docs;
                            return Container(
                                child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(_printDate(docAux[index]['date'])
                                    .toString()),
                                Text(
                                  docAux[index]['distance'].toStringAsFixed(2),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ));
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(
                      child: SpinKitCubeGrid(
                          size: 51.0, color: Colors.blue,));
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

String _printTime(int timeInMilliseconds) {
  String twoDigits(int n) {
    if (n >= 10) return "$n";
    return "0$n";
  }

  Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: timeInMilliseconds);
  String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
  String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
  if (duration.inHours > 0)
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  else
    return "$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
}

String _printDate(Timestamp timestamp) {
  var formattedAux = timestamp.toDate();
  var day = formattedAux.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  var month = formattedAux.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0');
  var year = formattedAux.year;

  return '$year' + '-' + '$month' + '-' + '$day';
}
```

This screen is the one I am using background location and when I go back to MainApp, Streambuilder doesn't update and returns snapshot.data null:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:carp_background_location/carp_background_location.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:timer_builder/timer_builder.dart';

class LocationStreamWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<LocationStreamWidget> createState() => LocationStreamState();
}

enum LocationStatus { UNKNOWN, RUNNING, STOPPED }

class LocationStreamState extends State<LocationStreamWidget> {
  final globalKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  LocationManager locationManager = LocationManager.instance;
  Stream<LocationDto> dtoStream;
  StreamSubscription<LocationDto> dtoSubscription;
  LocationStatus _status = LocationStatus.UNKNOWN;

  // Definitions
  List<LocationDto> _allPositions;

  List<LocationDto> _positions = <LocationDto>[];
  double totalDistance;
  double intermediaryDist;
  double distAux;
  double distLatLong;

  int totalTime;
  int intermediaryTime;
  int timeAux;
  List<LocationDto> _allPositionsInter;
  List<LocationDto> _positionsInter = <LocationDto>[];

  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    locationManager.interval = 1;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 0;
    dtoStream = locationManager.dtoStream;
    totalDistance = 0.0;
    intermediaryDist = 0.0;
    totalTime = 0;
    intermediaryTime = 0;
    _positions.clear();
  }

  void onData(LocationDto dto) {
    setState(() {
      if (_status == LocationStatus.UNKNOWN) {
        _status = LocationStatus.RUNNING;
      }

      _positions.add(dto);
      _allPositions = _positions;
      print(_positions.length);

      _positionsInter.add(dto);
      _allPositionsInter = _positionsInter;

      final firstTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
              _allPositionsInter.first.time ~/ 1)
          .toLocal();
      final lastTime =
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(_allPositionsInter.last.time ~/ 1)
              .toLocal();
      totalTime =
          intermediaryTime + lastTime.difference(firstTime).inMilliseconds;
      print(totalTime);
    });
  }

  void start() async {
    if (dtoSubscription != null) {
      dtoSubscription.resume();
    }
    dtoSubscription = dtoStream.listen(onData);
    await locationManager.start();
    setState(() {
      _status = LocationStatus.RUNNING;
    });
  }

  void pause() async {
    setState(() {
      intermediaryDist = totalDistance;
      intermediaryTime = totalTime;
      _positionsInter.clear();
      _allPositionsInter.clear();
      _status = LocationStatus.STOPPED;
    });
    dtoSubscription.cancel();
    await locationManager.stop();
  }

  String _printTime(int timeInMilliseconds) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }

    Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: timeInMilliseconds);
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    if (duration.inHours > 0)
      return "${twoDigits(duration.inHours)}:$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
    else
      return "$twoDigitMinutes:$twoDigitSeconds";
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    if (dtoSubscription != null) {
      dtoSubscription.cancel();
      dtoSubscription = null;
      _allPositions.clear();
      _allPositionsInter.clear();
      totalDistance = 0;
      intermediaryDist = 0.0;
      distAux = 0.0;
      _status = LocationStatus.STOPPED;
      totalTime = 0;
      intermediaryTime = 0;
      locationManager.start();
      if (_positions != null) {
        _positions.clear();
        _positionsInter.clear();
        _allPositionsInter.clear();
        locationManager.start();
      }
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        builder: (context) {
      return Scaffold(
        key: globalKey,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: locationManager.checkIfPermissionGranted(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      if (snapshot.data == false) {
                        return Text('No gps');
                      }
                      return Container(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                '${totalTime != null ? _printTime(totalTime) : '0'}',
                              ),
                              _getButtons(user),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _getButtons(UserClasse user) {
    final _currentDate = _positions?.isNotEmpty ?? false
        ? (DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(_positions[0].time ~/ 1)
            .toLocal())
        : 0;

    if (dtoSubscription == null)
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Begin'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: start),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    else if (_status == LocationStatus.RUNNING)
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Pause'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: pause),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    else if (_status == LocationStatus.STOPPED) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Back'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: start),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 15,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Stop'),
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {},
                onLongPress: () async {
                  _firestore
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc('user_id')
                      .collection('corridas')
                      .add({
                    'date': _currentDate,
                    'distance': 41.7,
                    'pace': 1244,
                    'average_speed': 12,
                    'runtime': 14134,
                    'max_speed': 41,
                    'max_altitude': 13,
                    'delta_altitude': 13,
                    'lat_first': -23.213,
                    'long_first': -23.213,
                    'polylines': 'feaf',
                    'markers': [1, 2, 3],
                  });
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Start'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () {}),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @TahaMalik Sorry, I've just added

Comment: It seems to be a library error, try using older versions.

Comment: Exactly @RahulChauhan, It is background locator causing this https://github.com/rekab-app/background_locator/issues/167.

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4108 cover of the issue also.

But I still couldn't solve it